# Remove seconds from html5/jquery digital clock format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clock, digital

I have this code

```
<script>                        
function displayTime() {
    var elt = document.getElementById("clock");  
    var now = new Date();                        
    elt.innerHTML = now.toLocaleTimeString();    
        setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);               
}
window.onload = displayTime;  
</script>
```

to run a simple digital clock but at the moment the format is hh:mm:ss and runs in 24 hour.

I would like the same clock to run in hh:mm but stay as 24 hour format. When I have tried different code to take the seconds off the clock freezes or only runs in 12 hour. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried to take the seconds off?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string yourself, using methods such as .getHours() & .getMinutes().

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayTime() {
        var elt = document.getElementById("clock");  
        var now = new Date();                        
        var t = now.getHours() +":"+ now.getMinutes();
        elt.innerHTML = t;
        setTimeout(displayTime, 30000);               
    }
    window.onload = displayTime;  
</script>
```

Comment: Check out the [javascript date object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate). Also, if you want to show 12 hour clock, you need to check if the hours is greater than 12, and subtract 12 from that. One useful library I've used when dealing with dates and times is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It might be useful if you plan to use it for a lot of date time manipulations across your project.